# setting scnnode presentation position

Tags: swift, core-animation, scenekit

I want to set the transform of both a given `scn:SCNNode` **and** its current presentation node, to a new value. However, I'm having trouble setting the presentation node. I've tried four ways:

1. Set presentation node's transform:

   ```
   scn.position              = newVal
   scn.presentation.position = newVal
   ```

   `scn.presentation.transform` is **read only** -- it can't be set. (BTW, setting the presentation node's transform compiles with no errors, perhaps something to clean up)
2. Use resetTransform():

   ```
   scn.position              = newVal
   scn.physicsBody.resetTransform()
   ```

   **does nothing**. The docs say it "Updates the position and orientation of a body in the physics simulation to match that of the node to which the body is attached". But it isn't changed. Not clear why!
3. Remove the physicsBody while setting:

   ```
   let pb                  = scn.physicsBody
   scn.physicsBody         = nil
   scn.position            = newVal
   scn.physicsBody         = pb
   ```

   This sets the presentation transform to newVal (**"yea!"**), but Physics does not work (**"boo!"**). Perhaps one cannot reuse a physics body.
4. Add a new physics body after setting:

   ```
   scn.position            = newVal
   scn.physicsBody         = SCNPhysicsBody(type:.dynamic, shape:nil)
   ```

   but alas, scn.presentation.position doesn't have newVal.

Thoughts?

Comment: I have learned the basic fact that you shouldn't change anything in the presentation node.  

Per item 2: resetTransform() seems to take effect only after the current thread exits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been noticing this as well in my SceneKit-using project.  The direct answer to your question is: *“The presentation node automatically updates its transform to match the scene node's transform.  If it doesn't seem to be updating, make sure the scene node's `isPaused` is set to `false`.”*  However, it's likely that your scene nodes are un-paused and/or you're not using animations at all, and yet this issue occurs.

I started noticing this issue happening intermittently on iOS 11 when everything in my project worked great on iOS 10.  I haven't touched `SCNAnimation`s or anything like that— I have my own animation system, so I just update my nodes' `.position` every `renderer(_:, updateAtTime:)`.

So AFAICT, the issue here isn't anything you're doing— the issue is that SceneKit has always been buggy and poorly-written *(some parts of the API still haven't been fully updated for Swift)*, and will likely remain buggy and poorly-written because it seems the SceneKit team has completely moved onto working on ARKit.  So the solution to your problem seems to be *“just try a bunch of stuff, setting `.position` more frequently than necessary, or at a different time in the update loop, or really hack-y solution that seems to work-around the issues in SceneKit”*.

For me, personally, I'm slowly working towards abandoning SceneKit in my project— I've mostly switched to custom Metal shaders, and then I'll do my own scene render loop, and eventually I'll replace the scene graph and `SCNNode` usage leaving me with zero reliance on the buggy mess that is SceneKit.

I wish I had better news for you, but I've been dealing with the weirdness of SceneKit for 2 years now.  It's unfinished garbage.

**Update:** I ended up “fixing” my presentation nodes misbehaving by using a dirty hack that adds a tiny amount of “wiggle” to the node's position each frame:

```
public func updateNode()
{
    let wigglePositionValue = SCNVector3(
        x: Float.random(in: -0.00001...0.0001),
        y: Float.random(in: -0.00001...0.0001),
        z: Float.random(in: -0.00001...0.0001)
    )
    self.scnNode.position = _locationModel.value + wigglePositionValue
}
```

Side-note: As expected, “jiggling” node positions like this also disallows SceneKit from doing some of its batching/rendering optimizations, and (in my experience) incurs a performance hit.  It's a horrible hacky work-around, only intended for worst-case scenarios *(“the client says we have to go live with the game this week or we don't get paid, and now this stupid SceneKit bug?!”)*

*So yeah… the real solution here is “don't use SceneKit”.*

Comment: Your comment about “just try a bunch of stuff" is what I did.  I think I tricked it to go through another render cycle before I looked at the presentation and that did it.  Your comment about the team moving on to ARKit is sad, but unfortunately par for the course. The swizzy demo has priority over continued support of last years kits. :( too.

Comment: @AllenKing I'm curious what your solution (“tricked it to go through another render cycle”) entails.  I'm currently phasing out my use of SceneKit for this and other reasons, but I'd like to be able to replace functionality one piece at a time (first, custom shaders, next custom render pipeline, then scene graph and update/render loop), so being able to trick SceneKit's update system for the time being would be useful to me.

Comment: This was a time when I had a few SceneKit bugs biting me at the same time and I was going fast, so my memory is limited: In the reposition routine, I set scn.position, did a resetTransform, and printed in the log that it didn't take. Then, in the outer loop, I did the whole reposition routine again and it took. The funny thing is that both reposition's were done immediately after creation of SCNScene, it's rootNode, physicsWorld and physicsBodies, before any trips through my SCNSceneRenderer delegate.

Comment: BTW: Is SceneKit still unfinished garbage in 2023 or did things improve in the meantime?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue using ARKit. Because physicsBody adjust itself according to presentation node instead of the node itself, and because the presentation node doesn't update immediately when you change the node's transform, the physicsBody you get might be weird.

**There is one solution I found recently**:

To change presentation node's transform, use SCNAction. For example, if you want to set position, use `node.runAction(SCNAction.move(by: SCNVector3, duration: 0))` instead of simply `node.position = SCNVector3`. This way, the presentation node immediately updates and you get the right physics.

In addition, this approach only works on the node itself (not applying to children). So **if you run action on the node's child, you still can't get the right presentation node and physics**. To change the **child node's** transform and presentation transform, use the `node.position = SCNVector3` approach.

To sum up, when changing node's transform, run an action, and when changing the node's children' transforms, directly set the transform.

Comment: Apparently, running an SCNAction on a node DOES affect its child nodes as well, except if their physicsBody is dynamic.  If their physicsBody is static or kinematic or if they have no physicsBody then they will move along with their parent node.